# How to tell angularjs form that the input value has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I built a sign up from using angularjs. The submitting process is OK. Then I want to make a validation of checking if the email is already registered. If exist, show the error message informing that the email exists. The problem I face is when user changes the email address, the submitted email is still the previous one. How to tell angular that the input value has changed and submit the newly inserted values.

My sign up form

```
<div ng-controller="signupController">
<form ng-submit="doSignup()">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2>
            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" autofocus="" ng-model="formData.email">
                <span class="text-danger">{{ emailExistError }}</span>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="formData.password">
                <input type="password" name="password_conf" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

The app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {

    })
    .controller('signupController', function ($scope, $http,$window) {

        $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.doSignup = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'signup.php',
                data: $.param($scope.formData),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .success(function (data) {

                $scope.login = data;

                if (data.status == 'ok') {
                    $('#successModal').modal('show');
                }
                else if (data.status == 'email exist'){
                    $scope.emailExistError = 'Email exist. Use different email';
                }
                else {
                    $('#failedModal').modal('show');
                }

            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: hmm.. I think it's weird.. how about use `then` instead of `success`?

Comment: Odd. I've tried to replicate your app without http request. It seems fine, look at [this](https://jsbin.com/lewovup/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Ok I check it by showing `{{formData}}`, apparently email address does change.  So why I still have that email exist error? What did I miss?

Comment: you seem to misunderstand the flow of things.  you first send data to the server, then if the server rejects it with `'email exist'`, you are setting **a different property** `$scope.emailExistError`.  When the user later changes the value of `$scope.formData.email`, it has no effect on `$scope.emailExistError`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$watch('email',function(newVal,oldVal){
if(newVal!=oldVal){
$scope.doSignup();
}});
```